# Frama-c Assertion

Tags: c, frama-c

Recently I have been working with **`frama-c`** and I have faced a problem which is a bit confusing.

I have written a very simple program in **`frama-c`** which is this:

```
void main(void)
{
    int a = 3;
    int b = 4;
    /*@ assert a == b;*/
}
```

I expect `frama-c` to say the assertion is not valid which in **`GUI`** this is shown by red bullet, but instead `frama-c` says **the assertion is not valid according to value** (under hypothesis), which is shown by orange-red bullet.

My question is why would `frama-c` say the assertion is not valid under hypothesis?

What are the possible hypotheses?

I am asking this because my program is very simple and I can't find any hypothesis or dependency in my program which is related to the assertion and I guess `frama-c` should just say the assertion is not valid.

Comment: Never used frama-c, but in some other formal verification systems this would be valid as long as the code was unreachable.

Comment: void main? ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative way to see the dependencies of a property proven under hypotheses is to use the `Report` plugin, on the command-line:

> $ frama-c -val c.c -then -report

```
[report] Computing properties status...

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- Properties of Function 'main'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[  Alarm  ] Assertion (file c.c, line 5)
            By Value, with pending:
             - Unreachable program point (file c.c, line 5)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- Status Report Summary
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1 Alarm emitted
     1 Total
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The *pending* information lists all the properties required to finish the proof. For statutes emitted by the Value/Eva plugin, the only dependences emitted will always be reachability ones.

(This is actually misleading: the status of the *n* th property actually depends on the statuses for the properties *k* with *k* < *n*. This would generate a dependency graph too big, so those dependencies are not tracked.)

Answer (score 2):

If you have `graphviz` configured with your Frama-C installation (i.e. it was available when Frama-C was configured, either manually or via `opam`), you can double-click the property in the Properties panel, and a window should open with the following dependency graph for the property:

[image: Property dependency graph for <code>assert a == b;</code>]

In it, we can see all the hypotheses used by a property, and so we see that the "under hypotheses" mentioned is that of the reachability of the assertion. Eva (`value` plug-in) computes an over-approximation of reachable states, so it cannot prove that a given state is reachable, only that it is *unreachable*.

Currently, the only plug-in which can definitely prove reachability statuses is [PathCrawler](https://frama-c.com/pathcrawler.html). However, in practice this is rarely an issue.